# Transparent image over texture in faces

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I have a problem about adding an image with transparent background over the already existing material in a group of faces (or a single face) of an object. I saw similar questions in the forum but none of those gave me the result that I am looking for.

As example, I have cube which has been unwrapped, and has a material with normal map, mapping, etc

[image]

Then I want to add and image with transparent background on only one of the faces to get something like this (fake image using gimp)

[image]

I tried several approaches (multiple uv mapping, using mix nodes, etc) without getting the desired result. I cannot properly combine the two images to get what I want.  Which would be the best approach to get this done?

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

MixRGB node should do it for you. Connect the alpha from the image with transparency and use it as a mix factor.

[image: MaskAlpha]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to put the image only on one face of the cube. The solution that you propose put it in all the faces.

Comment: Make 2 versions of the texture (2 separate materials) - one with the transparent one, and one without. Give the base (non-transparent) texture to the whole cube, then select one face, pick the second material (the one with the transparency) from the material properties window, and hit "Assign"

Comment: Thank you. I finally solved it following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn1KrLsGUUQ